# Microsoft Office 365 (microsoft teams migration from one tenant to another)

Tags: migration, office365, microsoft-teams

i have requirement to migrate microsoft teams from one region to another region tenant , i have gone through some of the tools like MigrationWIZ , cloudiway and Avepoint . but i havent done this kid of migration before , can anyone suggest how good the tools are ? and is there any other way to do this kind of migration and is there any microsoft  tool which can hep with this .

Comment: Please take a look at [https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/ms-teams-migration-one-tenant-to-another-office365-tenant/m-p/279349](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/ms-teams-migration-one-tenant-to-another-office365-tenant/m-p/279349)

Comment: Yup have seen this , have u used any of those tools for migration , just want to know feedback and which among them are good and trustworthy to go ahead .